# I want to truncate database table

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I add connection string in following and put it in web.config

```
<add name="cn" connectionString="data source=10.209.46.210;Initial Catalog=EDWP;User ID=kbanke2e;Password=passw0rd;Persist Security Info=True;Port=5480;Optimize for ASCII=True;" providerName="NZOLEDB"/>
```

on app.vb I try to coding following to truncate the table but error is populate

```
Protected Sub Button1_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim cnn As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("cn").ConnectionString
    Dim strSQL As String
    strSQL = "TRUNCATE TABLE EDWID02.EXT_RBS_SMN1S00648_1"
    Using connection As New SqlConnection("cnn")

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL, connection)
        cmd.Connection.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using

End Sub
```

The error is below

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification
>   starting at index 0.    Description: An unhandled exception occurred
>   during the execution of the current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about the error and where it
>   originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Format of the
>   initialization string does not conform to specification starting at
>   index 0.
>
> Source Error:
>
> ```
> Line 12:         Dim strSQL As String
> Line 13:         strSQL = "TRUNCATE TABLE EDWID02.EXT_RBS_SMN1S00648_1"
> Line 14:         Using connection As New SqlConnection("cnn")
> Line 15: 
> Line 16:             Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL, connection)
> ```

Comment: Gee, if only there was a way to know what the error is that you mention.  If only there was someone who had actually seen it who could tell us what what the error message was and any other information that was also provided.

Comment: I add the error of this programming

Comment: I sure hope that's not the real username and password.

Comment: It's real user and password to connect netezza

Comment: Cool, now we just need a public IP and we can truncate your table for you! But seriously, don't post your real connection info. and change your password to something actually secure.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Using connection As New SqlConnection(cnn)
```

You need to supply the actual connection string. You were passing the literal characters "cnn", which are invalid as a connection string, starting at index 0.

Comment: That appears to be correct but I'm not sure that that code will work even then.  That appears to be an OLE DB connection string for Netezza DBMS but the OP is creating a `SqlConnection` object, which is only for SQL Server.  I think that the OP needs to switch to using `OleDb` instead of `SqlClient` too.